# Improve Grails-Commandline performance

Tags: performance, command-line, grails

is there a way to improve the performance of the Grails commandline tasks. For example the test-app task is taking some time until all dependencies are checked, classes compiled etc. Even simple tasks like create-domain-class is taking some seconds to run.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942066/speeding-up-grails-test-app

Comment: on my new MBP (corei7) it can still take 2 seconds just to startup every command.  I agree with the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "grails interactive" shell for running unit tests, generating basic artifacts and so on. This way you don't have to pay the startup cost for every simple command.

Note that this didn't really work for integration tests last time I tried.