# Speeding up rails tests during development by keeping Rails in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

When running rspec tests on my rails app using "rake" or "rake spec", it takes a long time to initialize Rails and start running tests.

Is there a way to keep Rails loaded in memory and run tests against it? I'm hoping there's  something similar to using "grails interactive" like this [How to speed up grails test execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942066/speeding-up-grails-test-app) but for Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *almost* what [Spork](https://github.com/timcharper/spork) is all about.

Comment: Thanks! I've got spork running with in my Rails 3 development environment now. Looks like things will be much quicker when I'm ready for continuous integration too.

Answer (score 2):

See the most awesome railscast "How I test" http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test
This uses guard to run a relevant test every time you save a file so you know almost instantly if the code you have written has caused a pass or a fail. Also if you are running on linux then you can use the libnotify and libnotify-rails gems which pop up a window for you (totally unobtrusively) indicating a pass or failure so you don't have to keep checking the console.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Railscast called Spork that specifically discusses this problem at http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork and offers an excellent solution with a detailed walkthrough.